# How to apply onchange show/hide after saving

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have on change function when you select value on drop-down field will show or hide. My on change function is works fine.

But the problem is when I click save. The structured field for on-change is did not apply. It shows all of my fields instead of defined field.

Ok, Here's my structure.

First I call of my fields using php foreach loop.
example:

```
 <?php foreach($options as $key_option=>$val_option):?>
         <!--INPUT BOX -->
            <?php if($val_option['id'] == '1081' || $val_option['id'] == '1082' || $val_option['id'] == '1083' || $val_option['id'] == '1168'):?>


           <div class="col-lg-3" id="<?php echo $val_option['id']; ?>">
            <label class="control-label"><?php echo $required_notice . $val_option['option'] ?><?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?><i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="<?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>"></i><?php endif;?></label>

            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo form_input('option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key, set_value('option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key, isset($estate['option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key]) ? $estate['option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key] : ''), 'class="form-control ' . $val_option['type'] . '" id="inputOption_' . $key . '_' . $val_option['id'] . '" placeholder="' . $val_option['option'] . '" ' . $required_text . ' ' . $max_length_text) ?>

            <?php if (!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->prefix) || !empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->suffix)): ?>
                <?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->prefix . $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->suffix ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

This is how looks like
[image]

Then on change like this...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#inputOption_1_2').on('change',function(){
if( $(this).val()==="Apartment" ){
    //Unitinfo
$('#20').show(); //bedroom
$('#19').show(); //bathroom
$('#1176').show(); //type of floorplan
$('#1063').show(); //no. of parking
$('#1177').show(); //Indoor Area
$('#1078').show(); //Balcony Area
$('#1179').show(); //Terrace Area
$('#1191').show(); //Price
$('#1192').show(); //REF#
$('#1193').show(); //RERA #
$('#1194').hide(); //Storey
$('#1195').hide(); //Plot Area
$('#1196').hide(); //Hotel Brand
$('#1197').hide(); //Built up Area
$('#1198').hide(); //Type of use
$('#1199').hide(); //Total Capacity
$('#1200').hide(); //No of kitchen
$('#1201').hide(); //No of dining
$('#1172').hide(); //Total Area
$('#1202').hide(); //Total Built up area
$('#1203').hide(); //Total Plot Area
$('#1071').hide(); //License Authority
$('#1211').hide(); //Nature of Business
$('#1212').hide(); //Total Price
$('#1204').hide(); //Area
//Decor
$('#1000').hide(); //Furnish
$('#1084').hide(); //Decoration
$('#1085').hide(); //Kitchen Type
$('#1087').hide(); //Floor Materials
$('#1086').hide(); //Window type
$('#1088').hide(); //Window Type
$('#1091').show(); //Smart System
$('#1089').hide(); //Private Garage
$('#1013').hide(); //Private Swimming Pool
$('#1006').show(); //Built in Wardrobe
$('#1138').hide(); //BBQ Area
$('#1205').hide(); //Bathroom Type
$('#1061').hide(); //Fitted
$('#1092').hide(); //Pantry
$('#1206').hide(); //Shared Meeting Room
$('#1207').hide(); //Shared Reception
//View
$('#1080').show(); //Main Direction
$('#1136').show(); //Master Bed
$('#1137').show(); //Other Bed
$('#1167').show(); //Kitchen Direction
$('#1166').show(); //Entrance
$('#1181').show(); //Primary view
$('#1182').show(); //View from Master bed
$('#1183').show(); //View from Other bed
$('#1168').show(); //Kitchen View
//Brand
$('#1140').show(); //Cooker   
$('#1141').show(); //Fridge
$('#1142').show(); //Washing Machine
$('#1143').show(); //Dryer
$('#1144').show(); //Dishwasher
$('#1145').show(); //Floor
$('#1146').show(); //Furniture
$('#1147').show(); //Bathroom
$('#1208').hide(); //Elevator
//Status
$('#1170').show(); //Rent Status
$('#1193').show(); //Tenancy Vacating Letter
$('#1095').show(); //Vacant on transfer
$('#1148').show(); //Rent Period
$('#1092').show(); //Expirty Date
$('#1093').show(); //Vacating Letter
$('#1094').show(); //Vacating Date
//Building Info
$('#1057').show(); //Building Name
$('#7').hide(); //Community
$('#1187').hide(); //Sub Community
$('#1186').show(); //Master Community
$('#1003').hide(); //Developer
$('#1044').hide(); //Year Completion
$('#1209').hide(); //Community Management 
$('#1169').show(); //Building Management
$('#1005').show(); //Annual Service Charge
$('#1101').hide(); //Cooling System
$('#1002').hide(); //Cooker Type
$('#1103').hide(); //Total Floors
$('#1104').hide(); //Building Heigts
$('#1105').hide(); //Building Color
$('#1106').hide(); //Ext Material
}
else if.....
</script>
```

When making onchange will be like this

[image]

Then when I click save my will be like this. It shows like this..

[image]

It supposedly like from the 2nd image even when I click save also apply changes of show/hide fields.

Thankyou

Comment: can you be specific on your question ?

Comment: if you are trying to maintain the state of any of these items after saving you might look at cookies, sessionStorage or localStorage perhaps

Comment: @RamRaider I iknow a little bit with the session storage. As far I know It can show only fields "with" value.But my fields are fixed based on my "inputOption_1_2" with or without value it will show. This is possible?

Comment: `"But my fields are fixed based on my "inputOption_1_2" with or without value it will show."` - can you explain further?

Comment: @RamRaider based on my script I set the fields base on my dropdown value right?

Example: On Apartment value.

I show field 1,2,4,5 and 6 and hide the rest.

Then I put value 

On field 1 4 5 only then save.
If I apply session storage It will only show field 1,4,5 or field 1,2,4,5 and 6??

Answer (score 0):

my recommendation is that you radically simplify your design by managing the tab placement within the PHP layer only.  Accomplish this by using classes to create logical tab groups from the PHP layer.  Then toggling visibility of fields based on the class names.  This makes it a lot easier to manage the standard mistake of not being able to hide all the old fields when toggling tabs.  This also allows you to multi-tag fields that need to be in multiple places as needed.

For example:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 fields apartment decor" id="val_id">
```

then in the onchange event use the classes to toggle visibility.  once the if statement version is working, upgrade to switch statements.

```
$('#elem').change(function(e) {
   $('.fields').hide();  // hide all
   if ( $('#type).val() === "Apartment") {
      if ( $('#tab).val() === "Decor") {
        $('.apartment.decor').show();  // show apartment decor tab
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this but I little confuse about tabs.

I dn't have issues with the tabs.
I have issues with my individual fields after saving.

Comment: right - i mentioned the classes because its a lot easier to hide everything and show one tab.  probably what is going on now is that you aren't hiding everything again but are missing some fields to hide and just showing more.